# Преобразовать строку в букву на PHP

Tags: php

Есть некая строка $string

И есть некоторый набор букв/цифр в массиве. Допустим, 4 числа: 1 2 3 4

Задача состоит в том, чтобы предсказуемо, постоянно и равномерно преобразовывать строку в одну из букв/чисел, указанных в массиве, при этом не важно какой будет буква или число - важен лишь порядковый номер этого значения в массиве

Тоесть это некий очень упрощенный хеш

Comment: длину строки по модулю возьмите  и все

Answer (score 0):

> Допустим, 4 числа: 1 2 3 4

```
<?php

function simple_hash ($s) {

  $c = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  $a = unpack ('C*', $s);

  return $c [array_reduce ($a, function ($a, $n) {return $a += ceil ($n / 256);}, 0) % count ($c)];
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r (simple_hash ('Hello world!'), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

function simple_hash ($s) {

  $c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
  $a = unpack ('C*', $s);

  return $c [array_reduce ($a, function ($a, $n) {return $a += ceil ($n / 256);}, 0) % count ($c)];
}


while ($i < 17) {

    $i ++;

    $arr[simple_hash ($i)]++;

}

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 8
)
```